# How do I query RealmObject that have RealmList that contains specified value

Tags: realm

I have a `RealmObject` (let's say `Owner`) and it has `RealmList<Cat>`. `Cat` has a property `name`. How do I query for all the `Owner`s who have cat with specified name ?

I tried:

```
RealmResult<Owner> owners = realm.query(Owner.class)
                                    .contains("cats", "Garfield")
                                    .findAll();
```

But it does not work.

PS most probably duplicate but cant find.

Comment: And really sorry we forgot to doc it :( ... https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2047

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`.` can be used when query child object/list fields, for your case try below:

```java
RealmResult<Owner> owners = realm.query(Owner.class)
    .contains("cats.name", "Garfield")
    .findAll();
```

Comment: what to do if the column is of boolean type? Please suggest