# RealmList<String> contains specified value

Tags: android, realm

I have a RealmObject named `Activity`:

```
public class Activity extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    public String token;
    public RealmList<String> names;
    public RealmList<String> units;
    public RealmList<Float> points;
}
```

When querying, I want to return all `Activity` items which their `names` list contains some value.(not a `exactly matches`, much like a SQL `like` statement.)

I tried

```
val allActivities = realm.where(Activity::class.java).contains("names", str).findAllAsync()
```

But I got an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid query: field 'names' in
>   class 'Activity' is of invalid type 'STRING_LIST'.

I have tried [How do I query RealmObject that have RealmList that contains specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924574/how-do-i-query-realmobject-that-have-realmlist-that-contains-specified-value), but the type in the mentioned `RealmList` is extending `RealmObject`, while `String` is not. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the Realm version ?

Comment: Not yet supported https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5361

Comment: You can tell Realm that you'd want this feature by posting at https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513