# Realm recursive query - android

Tags: android, database, realm, realm-list

I have several instances in Realm: `FeedItem` that has field `movie` with type `Movie`. `Movie` contains field `showTimes` that is `List` of `ShowTime` objects.

```
-FeedItem:
  └ movie: Movie
      └ showTimes: List<ShowTime>
                           └ minPrice: Float
```

And I need to query all the `FeedItem` items that contains `Movie` that contains at least one `Showtime` with given value for `minPrice` field.

I could use something like this:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(FeedItem::class.java)
                                    .beginGroup()
                                    .equalTo(FeedItem::movie.name + "." + Movie::showTimes.name + "." + ShowTime::minPrice.name, 10f)
                                    .endGroup()
                                    .findAll()
```

But `showTimes` is the `List` and I need to check all the items.

Due to the existing architecture of project I can not query all the items `FeedItem` and then filter them. So I can't use simple solution like this one:

```
val feed = Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(FeedItem::class.java).findAll()

val filteredFeed = feed.filter { feedItem ->
    var b = false
    feedItem.movie.showTimes.forEach { showtime ->
        b = showtime.minPrice == 10f
    }
    b
}
```

And only way to solve my issue is to write one complex query to Realm. Tell me, please, how can I do that?

Comment: Why you cannot query all items?

Comment: Because query takes too long time. I haven't ability to use `findAllAsync()` and use callback here, because this block of code already represents `Observable` and the easiest way to solve my task is to use complex query (if it possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution: [How do I query RealmObject that have RealmList that contains specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924574/how-do-i-query-realmobject-that-have-realmlist-that-contains-specified-value)

So, in my case:

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(FeedItem::class.java).beginGroup()
          .greaterThanOrEqualTo(FeedItem::movie.name
                        + "."
                        + Movie::showTimes.name
                        + "."
                        + ShowTime::minPrice.name,
                        10f)
           .endGroup()
```

Comment: Beware that the `::_.name` might not work after using Proguard.